# (richfaces) set value from list in column

Tags: java, richfaces

I have crated a dataTable. This Table has an action which returns a list. This List is saved as `var="list"`. The Table has 4 columns. All column names should be taken from the list.
The first column name should be  list.get(0).getDescription(), the second column name shoul be list.get(0).getCompanyname(), the third should be list.get(1).getCompanyname() and the last list.get(2).getCompanyname().

Now, I don't know how I can access each object with the index fromList and set this as a column name?

Can I write java code in richfaces? i mean like this `<h:outputText value="#{list.get(0).getDescription()}" />` or  can I access this **value** in richfaces?

Comment: Datatable should be used in case when you want to represent each list item in separate row. In your case it looks like data grid with access to different items in the same row.

Comment: How can I do it? I don't understand how I can access  to different items in the same row? Can you please explain it me, with a example?

Comment: It depends on your design. Easiest way is prepare specific methods in bean which will return needed data per specific column. Or you can set data in column 1 and use ui:repeate for columns 2, 3 and 4.